# what is the [B] in "def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B"?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Immediately following foldLeft there is that [B] and I don't understand what it is.

I believe that it refers to the type of whatever it's operating on. Is it like a receiver in golang?

Comment: Is a type parameter / generic, there isn't anything similar in **Go**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: as of 1.18 Go has generics.

Answer (score 1):

Using `foldLeft` we are folding a foldable container containing element(s) of type `A` to produce an output of type `B`. `z` is the initial value and `op` is a function that takes two arguments of types `B` and `A` to produce a `B`. If the container is not empty, the folding process begins with `z` and an element from the container as inputs for `op`. This process continues with the result of `op` along with the next element from the container eventually producing a result of type `B`. If the container is empty, `z`, which is also of type `B`, is the result of `foldLeft`.

Eg: A list with different initial values and operations:

```
val ls = List(1, 2, 3)

ls.foldLeft(0)((acc, int) => acc + int) //6
ls.foldLeft(2)((acc, int) => acc + int) //8
ls.foldLeft("")((acc, int) => acc + int) //"123"
ls.foldLeft(List.empty[Int])((acc, int) => int :: acc) //List(3, 2, 1)
```

Here the type of `z` and the type of the result for a particular case is the same but varies over other cases. In scala, we can use a type parameter to represent this. In the case of `foldLeft` it is represented using `[B]`:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

We could have written the above examples like:

```
ls.foldLeft[Int](0)((acc, int) => acc + int) 
ls.foldLeft[Int](2)((acc, int) => acc + int) 
ls.foldLeft[String]("")((acc, int) => acc + int) 
ls.foldLeft[List[Int]](List.empty[Int])((acc, int) => int :: acc)
```

But, as the compiler could infer the type `B` from the value of `z`, this was not necessary.

Comment: Nice description - I wouldn't say that op is a tuple though. It's a function with two arguments of type A and B returning a another value of type B.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out, I have made the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to explain `foldLeft` is that it's like doing this:

```
var result = 0;
for (var i of myCollection) {
  result += i;
}
return result
```

`[B]` is a type parameter on the method, and it refers to the type of your `result` (in this case, `Int`), which is the same type as the "initial value" that you declare before your for-loop. `[A]` is the type of the values in `myCollection` (`var i`, which is also `Int` in my example).

Thinking about this code in very generic terms, you provide some initial state (`result = 0`), then in each step of the for-loop, you take an element from the collection, and apply some logic to combine that element with the current "state" to get the next state.

With `foldLeft`, `z: B` is the "initial state", and `op: (A, B) => B` is a function to combine an element from the collection (`A`) with the current state (`B`) and returns the next state.

So the code above could be rewritten as

```scala
myCollection.foldLeft(0) { (sum, next) => sum + next }
```

Or, using convenient shorthand for anonymous functions,

```scala
myCollection.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
```